# DB2 runstats not working for xml columns

Tags: xml, db2

I am running runstats command to update the runtime statistics of a particular table called "CUSTOMER" in DB2. The customer has two columns- CID (integer) and INFO (xml column).

After running the command, if I look into the SYSCOLDIST table, the information for column CID is populated correctly. But there is nothing filled for the INFO xml column. The same happens with a different table that has xml columns.

Please help..

Thanks,
-Keshav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0610nicola/index.html) for some tips on stats generation for XML columns.  You might try checking the error logs to see what's there - also specifically as per tip 11 using sampling.